# Examples of the use of Vector Autoregressive Models

Tags: reference-request, applied-econometrics, time-series

I am self-learning Vector Autoregressive Models currently, and have practiced on a few datasets. But I wanted to read some actual research papers that use VAR, so that I get an idea of the level of rigour in their use in actual research or the practical sides to be kept in mind to use them.

When I searched "Vector Autoregressive Models" or its variants in Google Scholar, it displays papers about VAR. I wanted to read papers which apply VAR to answer different questions, such as in monetary or fiscal policy etc. maybe.

Answer (score 2):

There is this [study](https://www.banque-france.fr/sites/default/files/medias/documents/wp733.pdf) from Banque de France using a Bayesian VAR to analyse and forecast macroeconomic indicators, authors are Gergely Ganics and Florens Odendahl.

Answer (score 2):

VAR models are typically used in macroeconomics, among other fields. Lütkepohl ["New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401728) (2005) (a textbook) contains an in-depth presentation of VAR models and includes some relevant examples.